# NAT instance and NACL configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have

1. two public subnet which has one NAT EC2 instance and one bastion host
2. one private subnet which has one EC2 instance

I am able to ping google.com from my bastion host but I am unable to do so from my private EC2 instnace.I have checked all steps mentioned here:-
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-internet-connectivity/

I think the problem is with my NACL.

INBOUND RULES OF THE NACL ATTACHED TO THE PRIVATE SUBNET
[image]

OUTBOUND RULES OF NACL ATTACHED TO THE PRIVATE SUBNET
[image]

Pinging google.com works in case I detach the NACLS from private subnet. Please verify these NACLS

NOTE: - 10.100.3.0/24 and 10.100.0.0/24 are the CIDRs of my public subnet

Comment: How does the inbound rules for the public subnet and outbound rules of the private subnet look? Did you disable src/dest check on the NAT instance?

Comment: Yes , I have disabled src/dest check . It works if i detach the NACL from the private subnet

Comment: OK can you provide the outbound rules of the NACL in the private subnet?

Comment: Yes , Done @ChrisWilliams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your outbound NACL rules are blocking all traffic except those destined to have a **final destination** of 2 private IP ranges.

Whilst the NAT might be in these subnets, the target is not, you should allow any IP ranges you want to be able to speak out to.

Comment: So , NAT gateway is sending response on HTTP ports  and since I do not have any inbound rules for it, I am getting this error ?

Comment: Basically you should be restricting the destinations in the private subnets NACLs, unless you can be sure that its final target is the NAT (which it is not). People would generally update the NACL of the public subnet (where the NAT is to restrict the internet outbound traffic).

Comment: I have added the updated inbound rules in the question above.It still doesn't work

Comment: Its the outbound rules of the private NACL that needs the access, preferably to the ip ranges of any destinations (if it could be any website on the internet then it would be 0.0.0.0/0).

Answer (score 3):

The NACL is stateless. That means you have to open the respective protocol and ports for outgoing requests and you also need inbound rules for the return traffic of outgoing requests. To allow a response to outgoing ping requests, it must allow inbound ICMP traffic. If you want to send HTTP/S requests, you must allow inbound traffic on the ephemeral ports on TCP.

You can learn more about Network ACLs and ephemeral ports [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html).

Comment: I have added the updated inbound rules in the question above.It still doesn't work

Comment: The inbound rules alone won’t be sufficient. You also have to open the required outbound rules.